# Offline meteor application using ground:db

Tags: meteor, offline, grounddb, meteor-mobile

I am working with offline support of Meteor Application. I have researched about this support but all are giving one answer 'ground:db'. I looked into that solution its really nice effort by @raix. I started with that package, Its already working project so first task i have done that all collection i have grounded with following syntax

```
var Users = Meteor.users;
if(Meteor.isClient){
     SmtGroundCollections.Users = Ground.Collection(Users);
}
```

After that i have tried with my offline application but still its showing loading and i am not getting my dom elements after that i have tried with that all waitOn subscription i have put on condition

```
if(Meteor.status().connected){
        /* my subscriptions */
}
```

After that i am able to see my dom and if i visited that page when i am online then after i am going offline i am able to see my data.

Now i am explaining my problems.

1) When i am calling my methods its not updating my ground collection if i am offline. I used below code for resume my methods

```
if(Meteor.isClient){

    Ground.methodResume([

        'addProfie',

        ' editProfile' ,

        ' deleteProfile ' ,
    ]);
}
```

Its working fine when i am coming from offline to online its syncing my data to server but i am not able to immediate effect.

2) If i want full application offline then i need to visit every page of my mobile application and then i can get that data in offline but its not possible so i want one centralise thing where i will press button and i can grounded my all data which i want offline.

So can anyone help me to solve above problem

Thanks in advance